# htaccess redirect with parameters and ports

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect through a htaccess file from url1 to url2 with parameters.

Example: 
http://www.sensotec.be:8081 => http://activation.sensotec.be:8081
http://www.sensotec.be:8081/lpweb/login.aspx => http://activation.sensotec.be:8081/lpweb/login.aspx

I know there are a lot of cases like this, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work for your case, it will keep everything after the website url, even the port:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^8081$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://activation.sensotec.be%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

[Here's](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=da3f8f2f-a511-5297-9b08-2794955ebf1d) a working example.

Comment: Okay thanks. Still one question if I go to http://sensotec.be/products it still need to be at http://sensotec.be/products so it's only with the port that need to be redirected.

Comment: @StefanieSmet I've edited the answer by adding `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8081$`, this should match only the urls with port 8081

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!